# How do I only center text on x-axis, but be able to move the y-axis in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to put text in the center of the screen, but also on top to label the text in the center. In order to center the text currently, I am using the code below...

```
info = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((info.current_w, info.current_h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

txt = font.render("some random message", True, color)

screen.blit(txt, txt.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center))
```

But I cannot find a way to modify the center using `get_rect()` to edit just the y-axis. I also could not find any more elaboration about the `get_rect()` function in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has the following attributes:

```
x, y 
top, left, bottom, right 
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery 
size, width, height
w,h
```

So you could set the `centerx` to the screen's `centerx` to make the rectangle centered without affecting the `y` value.

```
screen.blit(text, text.get_rect(centerx=screen_rect.centerx))
```

For completion, if you want it centered at the top, you could write

```
screen.blit(text, text.get_rect(midtop=screen_rect.midtop)
```

and centered at the bottom

```
screen.blit(text, text.get_rect(midbottom=screen_rect.midbottom)
```

Comment: Do you need to create a variable for midtop? Or does it already come with the library?

Comment: @KrimsonWolf The [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object already has all those attributes, so you should not need to create anything

Comment: For some reason, the new text isn't rendering. Does my screen size have anything to do with it? Using the center attribute works but the midtop doesn't show anything. Also sorry if I'm asking a lot of questions! I don't mean to be a bother!

Comment: @KrimsonWolf Did it render correctly before? Notice that in my example I've use the variable name `text` instead of your variable name `txt`. Your screen size shouldn't matter, as long as it's big enough to fit the text

Comment: Oh yes, I am using my own variable, and the when I apply the midcenter attribute to the new text, it works, but when I exchange it for midtop, there is no new text.

Comment: @KrimsonWolf It works for me. Are you sure you haven't introduced any other problems?

Comment: It may just be my personal computer as I created a new file with only the text function and the midtop attribute still wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't know if this might be the cause of the issue, but pygame is full screened.

Comment: @KrimsonWolf I've tried this on both in windowed and fullscreen, so it shouldn't be an issue. But if you created new file, did you make sure to call `pygame.display.update()`? Otherwise it won't update the screen. Create a full example with a both a game-loop, event-handling, and updating the window.

Comment: Instead of using pygame.display.update(), I have been using a while true loop to sceen.blit(). Is this bad practice or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219026/discussion-between-krimsonwolf-and-ted-klein-bergman).

Comment: `sceen.blit()` draws to a "image" (an internal buffer) that that exist only in memory. In other words, it's not visible. `pygame.display.update()` takes the "image" (buffer) and draws it onto the physical screen so that you can see it. Without `pygame.display.update()`, you can only see blackness (or whatever was last updated to the screen).

Comment: Okay sorry that it took a while. I added in the pygame.display.update() function and it works like a charm! Thanks so much for you help!